# Fetch emails from Gmail via OAuth2

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to fetch emails from gmail using PHP and CodeIgniter, and an OAuth2 library. I have already got OAuth2 set up to get the users access token, etc. I can get the users info by doing

```
public function get_user_info(OAuth2_Token_Access $token)
{
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&'.http_build_query(array(
        'access_token' => $token->access_token,
    ));

    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    return array(
        'uid' => $user['id'],
        'nickname' => url_title($user['name'], '_', true),
        'name' => $user['name'],
        'first_name' => $user['given_name'],
        'last_name' => $user['family_name'],
        'email' => $user['email'],
        'location' => null,
        'image' => (isset($user['picture'])) ? $user['picture'] : null,
        'description' => null,
        'urls' => array(),
    );
}
```

What I want to do now is fetch some emails. I've googled for some code on how to get emails but the only thing I can see is `https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/`. I found this on the Google OAuth2 Playground but I can't figure out how to use it apart from navigating to it directly.

Can anyone give me some suggestions? Ideally I want to fetch emails that are not just new (this seems to be what the link above does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a REST-based interface you can currently only get the [unread messages feed](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed). If you want to access all emails of a user, you have to use IMAP. Google developed a method to do [IMAP/SMTP authentication using OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview) that you can use.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks. I gather this requires an unblocked 993 port? "Incoming connections to the IMAP server at imap.gmail.com:993 require SSL". My hosting provider won't unblock this for me which I why I decided to try the OAuth route instead

Comment: I don't think that would be a problem, as your server does not need to accept incoming connections on port 993, but that question is probably better suited at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Sorry I meant outgoing connection to 993 are blocked by my hosting company. I'll post a question on SF.

Comment: Hi Jen, do you know if it's possible to pass the users details when using the unread messages feed?

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to pass and where?

Comment: Ideally I want to lookup emails from multiple users' mailboxes. So I'll need to inform google on what user's mailbox I want to search

Comment: After a user authorizes your application, you get an *access token* and a *refresh token* per user. If you use the *access token* for user A to authenticate to IMAP, you get access to user A's mailbox, if you use the *access token* for user B to authenticate to IMAP, you get access to user B's mailbox.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was that https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/ doesn't seem to take any parameters like the example in my question does

Comment: You have to include an OAuth authorization header into your HTTP request. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi for how this should look like. Providing the access token in the query string AFAIK doesn't work here.